# Pycap not working in script

Tags: python

i m trying to capture ethernet packet using pycap http://pycap.sourceforge.net/. when i use following command on python prompt with root privileges, it is working

```
>>>import pycap.capture
>>>p = pycap.capture.capture("wlan0")
>>>p.next()
(Ethernet(type=0x608, 00:1b:b1:46:53:5d -> ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff), ARP(op=0x1, protocol=0x800,     00:1b:b1:46:53:5d (192.16.68.10) -> 00:00:00:00:00:00 (192.16.110.39)), '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 1307898356.222398)
```

But if i run these commands as a script, i m getting following error

```
>>>sudo python pycap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycap.py", line 2, in <module>
  from pycap import *
  File "/home/nikhil/Code/Python/pycap.py", line 5, in <module>
  p = capture.capture(device)
  NameError: name 'capture' is not defined
```

Any suggestions? 
pycap http://pycap.sourceforge.net/ says it is requires python2.3 and im using python2.6. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script using `pycap` is called `pycap` itself, so `import pycap` imports itself (`.` is usually the first directory on the import path). Because imports are caches, this doesn't lead to infinite recursion but instead gives you a reference to your own module, which of course doesn't define `capture` or anything else. Rename it.